# Callings fragments from listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I have a `fragment` that contains a `listview`. When I press the position `0` of my `listview` I want to open another `fragment` but I can't call it. I think there is a problem with the `managerFragment` but I'm not sure.

Here is  my code from `Frm_principal` that contains the `listview` in position `0`

I want to call `frmCliente`

```
 `package com.example.programacion.ventasje.Principal;

     import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.example.programacion.ventasje.Cliente.Frm_Cliente;
import com.example.programacion.ventasje.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * Created by Programacion on 31/07/2015.
 */
public class Frm_principal extends Fragment {

    TextView tv_funcion,tv_descripcion;
    ImageView img_principal;
    ListView listview_principal;
    ArrayAdapter<Principal> adapter;

    Principal dato;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_frm_principal,container,false);
        inicializarComponentesUi(rootView);
        inicializarListaContactos();
        inicializarDatosLista();
        listview_principal.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position==0) {

                    Fragment newFragment = new Frm_Cliente();
                    FragmentTransaction asd = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    asd.replace(R.layout.layout_frm_principal,)



                }
                }
        });

        return(rootView);
    }

    private void inicializarDatosLista() {
        Principal nuevo = new Principal("Cliente","Añadir modificar o anular clientes",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_cliente));
        adapter.add(nuevo);
    }

    private void inicializarListaContactos() {
        adapter = new PrincipalAdapter(getActivity(),new ArrayList<Principal>());
       listview_principal.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    private void inicializarComponentesUi(final View view) {
        tv_funcion = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_funcion);
        tv_descripcion = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_descripcion);
        img_principal =(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_principal);
        listview_principal =(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview_principal);


    }


}
`
```

and here is the frm cliente class that i want to call

```
 package com.example.programacion.ventasje.Cliente;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.programacion.ventasje.R;


/**
 * Created by Programacion on 30/07/2015.
 */
public class Frm_Cliente extends Fragment {




    private TextView tvCliente,tvCentro,tvOficio,tvLocalidad;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_frmcliente,container,false);
        inicializarComponentesUi(rootView);
        return(rootView);
    }


    private void inicializarComponentesUi(final View view) {
        tvCliente = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_cliente);
        tvCentro = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_centro);
        tvOficio = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_oficio);
        tvLocalidad = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_localidad);


}

}
```

Comment: you can't call it mean? What is your error? Does app crashes? If so post your stack trace.

Comment: i don t know how to call the fragment to frm cliente if you see in the frm_principal method  On item click im trying to call the class  frm_cliente extends fragment but i tried everything and it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to commit the transaction.

Inside your `onCLickListener`

```
 Frm_Cliente newFragment = new Frm_Cliente();
 FragmentTransaction asd = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 asd.replace(R.layout.layout_frm_principal,newFragment)
 ads.commit();
```